# How do I execute a script on button press (and in the end, transfer to another URL)?

Tags: php, javascript, button

Trying to provide some guidance to a coder of an HTML landing page. We are running a display ad campaign to get someone to apply for a credit card, and in particular, are running a CPC campaign across a network. We take people from the ad to a landing page, and after they click on an Apply Now button, they go to the bank.

The network is going to optimize ad placements on the firing of a conversion pixel. We cannot program the ultimate Thank You page or even the application page as they are at the other company (our credit card servicing bank).  Our only shot at something better than a click optimization is to place the pixel "behind" the Apply Now button.

Can someone suggest a simple way to code the button? I am assuming that we could execute a snipet of script and one line would be the pixel and another the transfer to the other website.  Our coder says this is not possible (to execute pixel code and then transfer off of page to a new URL).  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is this about a conversion pixel? And what is this putting it under the button? wat

Comment: Is this definition of a pixel not your definition of a pixel? Your question is confusing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel

Comment: Here is our situation (overview and nos. 1, 2, and 3): http://www.vertster.com/blog/2009/07/when-conversion-tracking-is-impossible-use-a-conversion-proxy/

Comment: And here is the ad network pixel we need to "fire":

Comment: <img src="http://a1.interclick.com/univPixel.aspx?g=e2e72bb3-a0c0-48a7-a682-cc393a350f08"/>

Comment: What we want to do is fire this line ONLY when someone presses the button and then immediately take them to the other website URL

Answer (score 0):

As an answer of the title, couse in the rest i didn't understand the content of the question, you can use "onclick" to execute a function, then, with `window.location` redirect /open another URL.
Something like this:

```
<button onclick="functionName()">Test</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function functionName(){
  // your code, Ajax to access a php script
  return window.location = 'url_to_redirect';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will pass along. As I mentioned in several follow up comments, the "// your code, Ajax to access a php script" needs to be the <img src="a1.interclick.com/...> line. Then, as you show, I can transfer the visitor to another URL using the return window.location line. Running the <img src=...> will work in that function, no?

Answer (score 0):

Guessed HTML:

```
<form id="form1">
<img src="blank.gif" id="pixel" />
<input type="button" id="subbut" />
</form>
```

Plain JS:

```
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("subbut").onclick=function() {
    var pix = document.getElementById('pixel');
    pix.onload=function() { document.getElementById("form1").submit() }
    pix.src='http://a1.interclick.com/someprocess?someparameter=...';
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will pass this along as well.